# jQuery Mobile get id of clicked item that caused page transition, after page transition has taken place

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile application with two "pages".  On the first page is a Google map, and on the second page is a listview of buildings, where each list item has an id associated with it.  When the user clicks a building, the map is meant to pan to that building and show a marker.  However, one of the quirks of jquery mobile is that I have to call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` and `map.panTo(somePosition)` *after* the page transition takes place, otherwise the map shows up funky.  I am tapping into the jQuery Mobile `pageshow` event to do this.  My question is, is there anything either in the `pageshow` event handler arguments or any way of attaching something to the `pageshow` event handler arguments that will allow me to identify the id of the list item that was clicked which caused the page transition in the first place, so I can use this to determine where to pan the map to?

At the moment, I'm having to do it in a round about kind of way, where I tap into the click event of the selected list item, store the selected list item id in a global variable and then use that global variable later on when in the `pageshow` event handler.

So something like:

```
var selectedBuilding;

$('a.buildingSelect').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selectedBuilding = $(this).attr("data-buildingNum");
});


$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    if (ui.prevPage.attr('id') === "buildingSelect") {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.panTo(selectedBuilding);
    }
});
```

Apart from being a little messy, one of the problems with this is if the user didn't select a building number at all, such as when they press the 'back' button on the building list page.  In this case, the `pageshow` event handler still gets executed, though the selected building will be either non existent if the user hasn't selected a building previously, or will cause the map to pan to the *last* selected building if they have selected a building previously, which isn't actually the intended behaviour.  I am sure I could make some additional global variables available to both event handlers to code around this, but it would be a little messy.  Ideally what I'm looking for is a way to only have to bind to the `pageshow` event and from within the binded function be able to derive which building id was clicked.

I am still relatively new to jQuery and javascript in general, so please keep this in mind.  Though I've had a bit of a play with the javascript debugging tools in Chrome, I'm still not really sure how I would go about effectively finding what information is made available in the `ui` argument to the `pageshow` event handler, which I imagine would be a good start towards solving problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stick the `pageshow` event handler inside `buildingSelect`'s click handler, and use the syntax that allows you to pass data through event binders: `.live( eventType, eventData, handler )` from http://api.jquery.com/live/.

But then you'd have to `die` the other live `pageshow` handlers before doing this.  If it was me, I'd just clean up the way you're storing those global variables and call it a day.  Maybe put them in a nice object that sits off a namespace so it's safer.

EDIT:  changed my incorrect colloquial "destroy" to the correct `die`.  So you would want to die the event handlers as in `$('div').die()` or any of the other variations explained in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/die/

Comment: can you elaborate for a newb how/why I would need to destroy the "other" live pageshow handlers?

Comment: sorry, i sometimes say silly things.  It's called die not destroy, I edited.

Comment: i've accepted this as the answer rather than my own, as you've done all the legwork.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Milimetric's answer, here is what I essentially did:

```
var selectedBuilding;

function rejigMap(event ui) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.panTo(selectedBuilding);
    $('div').die('pageshow', rejigMap);
}

$('a.buildingSelect').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selectedBuilding = $(this).attr("data-buildingNum");
    $('div').live('pageshow', rejigMap);
});
```

By only creating the `live` pageshow listener when a building is selected, and then destroying (`die`ing) it immediately after I've executed the code I need to, it removes the problem of `rejigMap` hanging around and listening to unrelated `pageshow` events, such as would fire when the user presses the "back" button and hasn't selected a building at all.  I *believe* this could be refactored a little more by following Milimetric's suggestion to use `.live(eventType, eventData, handler)` to actually pass through the selected building to `rejigMap`, which would allow the global variable to be eliminated completely.